# In my barchart, all my categorical strings overlap each other

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart, scenebuilder

So I'm still fairly new to java and javaFX or programming in general. I started to try to create a statistics programm for fishing. Today I wanted to play around with some Barcharts and randomly filled in some values. The problem I have now is:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZGbI.jpg)

The two strings "Salmoniden" and "Cypriniden" overlap each other and i don't know why.
My Code is as follows:

My Controller Class:

```
@FXML
    private BarChart<String, Integer> barchartStatistik ;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis numAxis;

    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis catAxis;


    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> cbox_statistiken;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
public void auswahl(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        String ausgewählteStatistik = cbox_statistiken.getValue();
        switch(ausgewählteStatistik){ 
        case "Fischfamilien": 
            XYChart.Series<String, Integer> dataSeries1 = new XYChart.Series<String, Integer>();
             dataSeries1.setName("Fischfamilien");
             dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Integer>("Salmoniden", 544));
             dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Integer>("Cypriniden", 357));
             barchartStatistik.getData().add(dataSeries1);

            break; 

        default: 
            System.out.println(""); 
        } 

    }




}
```

My FXML-file:

```
<BarChart id="barchartStatistik" fx:id="barchartStatistik" barGap="5.0" categoryGap="20.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="495.0" prefWidth="600.0" title="Statistiken">
        <xAxis>
          <CategoryAxis id="catAxis" fx:id="catAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis id="catAxis" fx:id="numAxis" side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </BarChart>
```

This of course is just a snippet of the code, i hope this is sufficient.

I tried altering the Gap-values without changing anything with that.

Comment: Does it fix itself if you cause the chart to resize (e.g. by resizing the window)? What happens if you set the chart's `animated` property to false?

Comment: @Slaw You were right with both options yet I want to keep it animated and have setResizable on false anyway. Is there any way to still have it displayed accurately?

Comment: Since what's happening is in all likelihood a bug, not having the chart animated is probably the easiest workaround. You could try messing around with forcing a layout. What if you add the `Series` to your chart before adding the `Data` to the `Series`?

Comment: @slaw I tried adding series to chart before, but didnt make a difference. Anyway, I will keep the animations off then. Thank you for your superfast help, you saved my day!